Relation between $[\mathbb{C}(t):\mathbb{C}(f,g)]$ and $[\mathbb{C}(t):\mathbb{C}(t^nf,t^mg)]$
Let $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ and assume that $[\mathbb{C}(t):\mathbb{C}(f,g)]=d \geq 1$.
Let $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ (here $\mathbb{N}$ includes zero) and denote $R_{n,m}=\mathbb{C}(t^nf,t^mg)$.

Question: Is it possible to determine in terms of $d,n,m$ (not just to give an upper bound) the degree of $[\mathbb{C}(t):\mathbb{C}(t^nf,t^mg)]$, denote it by $D{n,m}$?

I guess it is a good idea to begin with considering $d \in \{1,r\}$, $n \in \{0,1,p\}$,
$m \in \{0,1,q\}$, where $p,q,r$ are prime numbers, different or not.

If $n=m=0$, we have $R_{0,0}=\mathbb{C}(f,g)$ and we assumed that $[\mathbb{C}(t):\mathbb{C}(f,g)]=d$, so we are done.

If $n=1,m=0$, then $R_{1,0}=\mathbb{C}(tf,g)$; it is already not clear what $D_{1,0}$ is. For example, $f=t^2,g=t^3$, $\mathbb{C}(t^2,t^3)=\mathbb{C}(t)$, so $d=1$. Then $\mathbb{C}(tf,g)=\mathbb{C}(t^3,t^3)=\mathbb{C}(t^3)$, so $D_{1,0}$ for $(f,g)=(t^2,t^3)$ is $3$.


The second example shows that the degrees of $f$ and $g$ are relevant, so let us denote them by $d_f,d_g$, and now we wish to find for a pair $(f,g)$, the degree $D_{n,m}$ is terms of $d,n,m,d_f,d_g$.
Any help is welcome. Thank you.
Maybe it is better to concentrate on the special case $n=m$ and $\gcd(d_f,d_g)=1$. We get $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(t)$, so $d=1$. But not necessarily $\gcd(d_{t^{n}f},d_{t^{n}g})=1$.
